# java.io.IOException: Write error: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, exception

I've been encountering this error message from time to time.

```
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814): java.io.IOException: Write error: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativewrite(Native Method)
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.access$600(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:55)
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:583)
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:175)
11-14 10:46:04.693: W/System.err(14814):    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:158)
```

Any ideas?

I've seen the same problem here: 
http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=970

They say it's just a connection problem. Is it?
Thanks

Comment: wow, am I missing something.  Anyone can enlighten me regarding this?  Casting downvote without even explaining why.

Comment: You haven't posted an explanation of what you are trying to do, what might cause this or any code. So unless someone has every occurrence of this error memorized, we probably won't be able to help you...

Answer (score 2):

It could be 'just a temporary connection problem', but it could also be that you are trying to speak SSL to a non-SSL server. If you were using JSSE instead of OpenSSL the exception message might even say so.